Uncaught TypeError: $(...).froalaEditor is not a function.... This is my problem
I have conflicting jquery versions, the lastest jquery 3.6.0 and then Froala's 2.4.2 I believe.  As the process loads jquery and then Froala they interact and Froala overwrites the 3.6.0.  I need both versions to work in unisons so that I can save to my database. There have been similar problems that I have seen from past years, that is where I got noConflict from and setting a timeout.  If I missed a conversation that explained my problem better please just point me in the direction, Thank You.
I have tried noConflict() with no avail.
Tried moving all code to the actual page with no success.
Taken Jquery 3.6.0 out and this breaks my code further.
I have set a timeout for Froala with no victory.


@model List<jcperrestclient.JcpeRwebsitePageContentCommitteeDOA>
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";

    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}
<h2>Committee</h2>
<body>
    <div>
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            <div class="container-fluid box mt-5">
                <div class="row">
                    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)

                    {
                        <div class="col-md-10" id="section1">
                            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@(Model[i].CreatedBy)" />
                            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@(Model[i].CreatedDate)" />
                            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@(Model[i].UpdatedDate)" />
                            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@(Model[i].UpdatedBy)" />
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <strong><label asp-for="@(Model[i].CreatedBy)"></label></strong>
                                    <input asp-for="@(Model[i].CreatedBy)" readonly style="border: none" />
                                    <br />
                                    <strong><label asp-for="@(Model[i].CreatedDate)"></label></strong>
                                    <input asp-for="@(Model[i].CreatedDate)" readonly style="border: none" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <strong><label asp-for="@(Model[i].UpdatedBy)"></label></strong>
                                    <input asp-for="@(Model[i].UpdatedBy)" readonly style="border: none" />
                                    <br />
                                    <strong><label asp-for="@(Model[i].UpdatedDate)"></label></strong>
                                    <input asp-for="@(Model[i].UpdatedDate)" readonly style="border: none">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label id="lblSuccess" style="color: red">@ViewBag.lblSuccess</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label asp-for="@(Model[i].PageTitle)" class="control-label col-md-1"></label>
                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                    <textarea asp-for="@(Model[i].PageTitle)" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your text here" id="txtEditor"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <span asp-validation-for="@(Model[i].HtmlContentCurrent)" class="text-danger">this is the spot?</span>
                                <textarea asp-for="@(Model[i].HtmlContentCurrent)" id="froala-editor" name="Content"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-md-1 offset-md-1">
                                    <input type="button" id="buttonCancel" name="stringValue" value="Cancel" title="Cancel these changes" class="btn btn-outline-dark" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <input type="button" id="buttonSave" name="stringValue" value="Save" title="Save your changes" class="btn btn-outline-dark" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <input type="button" value="Show/Hide Preview" title="Html Preview" onclick="showDiv()" class="btn btn-outline-dark" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2" id="section2" style="font-family: arial; text-align: left;">
                            <h4>Page Content Properties</h4>
                            <strong><label asp-for="@(Model[i].AdminControllerName)"></label></strong>
                            <input asp-for="@(Model[i].AdminControllerName)" readonly style="border: none" />
                            <br />
                            <strong><label asp-for="@(Model[i].AdminControllerAction)"></label></strong>
                            <input asp-for="@(Model[i].AdminControllerAction)" readonly style="border: none" />
                            <br />
                            <strong><label asp-for="@(Model[i].PublicControllerName)"></label></strong>
                            <input asp-for="@(Model[i].PublicControllerName)" readonly style="border: none" />
                            <br />
                            <strong><label asp-for="@(Model[i].PublicControllerAction)"></label></strong>
                            <input asp-for="@(Model[i].PublicControllerAction)" readonly style="border: none" />
                            <br />
                            <strong><label asp-for="@(Model[i].PublicViewName)"></label></strong>
                            <input asp-for="@(Model[i].PublicViewName)" readonly style="border: none" />
                            <br />
                            <strong><label asp-for="@(Model[i].HasRightSideBar)"></label></strong>
                            <input asp-for="@(Model[i].HasRightSideBar)" readonly style="border: none" />
                            <br />
                            <strong><label asp-for="@(Model[i].RightSideBarName)"></label></strong>
                            <input asp-for="@(Model[i].RightSideBarName)" readonly style="border: none" />
                            <br />
                            <strong><label asp-for="@(Model[i].HasPartialView)"></label></strong>
                            <input asp-for="@(Model[i].HasPartialView)" readonly style="border: none" />
                            <br />
                            <strong><label asp-for="@(Model[i].PartialViewName)"></label></strong>
                            <input asp-for="@(Model[i].PartialViewName)" readonly style="border: none" />
                            <br />
                            <strong><label asp-for="@(Model[i].IsDeleted)"></label></strong>
                            <input asp-for="@(Model[i].IsDeleted)" readonly style="border: none" />
                            <br />
                            <strong><label asp-for="@(Model[i].DateDeleted)"></label></strong>
                            <input asp-for="@(Model[i].DateDeleted)" readonly style="border: none" />
                            <br />
                        </div>

                        <div id="previewDiv" style="display:none; border: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 10px; margin-top: 20px;">
                            <h4>HTML Preview</h4>
                            <div id="previewContent"></div>
                        </div>

                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>
    <!-- Include Froala Editor CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/froala-editor/css/froala_editor.pkgd.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/froala-editor/css/froala_style.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Include jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Include Froala Editor JS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/froala-editor/js/froala_editor.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include Bootstrap JS (if needed) -->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include your custom JS -->
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

    <script>
        //This makes jquery a variable and i can implement it like dependency injection this way it does not interact with Froala-->
        var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

        $j(document).ready(function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                initializeFroala();
            }, 1000); // 1 second delay to ensure Froala is fully loaded
            function initializeFroala() {
                new FroalaEditor('#froala-editor', {
                    key: "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    attribution: false,
                    heightMin: 300,
                    heightMax: 600,
                    toolbarSticky: true,
                    imageInsertButtons: ["imageBack", "|", "imageUpload", "imageByURL"],
                    quickInsertButtons: ['image', 'table', 'ul', 'ol'],
                    toolbarButtons: {
                        'moreText': {
                            'buttons': ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'textColor', 'insertHR', 'strikeThrough', 'subscript', 'superscript', 'fontFamily', 'fontSize', 'clearFormatting'],
                            'buttonsVisible': 5
                        },
                        'moreLink': { 'buttons': ['|', 'insertLink'] },
                        'moreParagraph': {
                            'buttons': ['|', 'outdent', 'indent', 'formatUL', 'formatOLSimple', 'align', 'paragraphFormat', 'paragraphStyle', 'lineHeight', 'quote'],
                            'buttonsVisible': 5
                        },
                        'moreImage': { 'buttons': ['|', 'insertImage'] },
                        'moreRich': {
                            'buttons': ['|', 'insertTable', 'emoticons', 'specialCharacters']
                        },
                        'moreMisc': {
                            'buttons': ['undo', 'redo', 'spellChecker', 'fullscreen', 'selectAll', 'html', 'help'],
                            'align': 'right',
                            'buttonsVisible': 2
                        }
                    },
                    imageUploadURL: getCurrentPath(),
                    imageUploadParams: {
                        id: 'my_editor'
                    },
                    events: {
                        'contentChanged': function () {
                            document.getElementById('previewContent').innerHTML = this.html.get();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            function getCurrentPath() {
                var uploadURL;
                switch (window.location.hostname) {
                    case 'intranet':
                        uploadURL = '/EditingPages/JCPeRServiceAPI/UploadFiles';
                        break;
                    case 'devi':
                        uploadURL = '/EditingPages-devi/JCPeRServiceAPI/UploadFiles';
                        break;
                    case 'localhost':
                        uploadURL = '/JCPeRServiceAPI/UploadFiles';
                        break;
                    default:
                        uploadURL = '/default-endpoint'; // Default upload URL
                }
                return uploadURL;
            }
            // Recognize the save button click event
            $j('#buttonSave').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault(); // This overrides the default form submission so that the following code can be implemented
                var formData = {
                    createdBy: $j('#CreatedBy').val(),
                    createdDate: $j('#CreatedDate').val(),
                    updatedBy: $j('#UpdatedBy').val(),
                    updatedDate: $j('#UpdatedDate').val(),
                    pageTitle: $j('#PageTitle').val(),
                    htmlContentCurrent: $j('#froala-editor').froalaEditor('html.get')
                };
                // This is the save request with ajax
                $j.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("SaveCommitteeContent", "Home")', // This is the backend endpoint
                    type: 'POST', // What type of endpoint it is
                    data: JSON.stringify(formData), // Converts the data to JSON format for the database to accept the information
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    headers: {
                        'RequestVerificationToken': $j('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() // Token for security
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response.success) {
                            $j('#lblSuccess').text('Content saved').css('color', 'green');
                        } else {
                            $j('#lblSuccess').text('Content failed to save').css('color', 'red');
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        $j('#lblSuccess').text('An error has broken your existence, welcome to the Matrix Neo').css('color', 'blue');
                    }
                });
            });
            function showDiv() {
                var previewDiv = document.getElementById('previewDiv');
                var previewContent = document.getElementById('previewContent'); // Add reference to content area
                if (previewDiv) {
                    if (previewDiv.style.display === "none") {
                        previewDiv.style.display = "block";
                        // Update the preview content with the HTML from Froala
                        previewContent.innerHTML = FroalaEditor.INSTANCES[0].html.get();
                    } else {
                        previewDiv.style.display = "none";
                    }
                } else {
                    console.error("Preview div not found!");
                }
            }
        });
    </script>

</body>




This is what jQuery.noConflict() is intended for. You need to show how you tried to use it, then we can help you fix it.

I have no.Conflict in my code, but dont know if it is properly coded.

$j('#froala-editor').froalaEditor should be $jQuery('#froala-editor').froalaEditor. That should use the version of jQuery that was loaded by froala, not the version you loaded later.

froala_editor.pkgd.min.js - see if you can get a version of froala that isn't packaged with jquery.

Either run $j = $.noConflict() before you load the conflicting jquery or change var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); to var $j = jQuery.noConflict(true); -see this answer (and comments)

The error in the title $(...).froalaEditor is not a function is because of the current .noConflict - it's removing the jquery at the time you call .noConflict - and that time (at the moment) is after you load floala (ie jquery 2 with the froala plugin) - so when you call $(..).froalaEditor it's no longer there.   Looks like froala doesn't follow jquery best practices!

Thank you everyone, i will try each answer and give a response back on the best outcome.

An alternative way for your requirement, you could just get the value by the following code :
htmlContentCurrent: $j('#previewContent').text()

BTW, your view contains for loop, what you did could not get the correct value in each loop. You need define unique id for the input and define the current index by using data-index like below:
<input type="hidden" asp-for="@(Model[i].CreatedBy)" id="CreatedBy_@i" />
<input type="hidden" asp-for="@(Model[i].CreatedDate)" id="CreatedDate_@i" />
<input type="hidden" asp-for="@(Model[i].UpdatedDate)" id="UpdatedDate_@i" />
<input type="hidden" asp-for="@(Model[i].UpdatedBy)" id="UpdatedBy_@i" />

//other code no need change....

<div class="form-group row">
    <label asp-for="@(Model[i].PageTitle)" class="control-label col-md-1"></label>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <textarea asp-for="@(Model[i].PageTitle)" id="PageTitle_@i" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your text here"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
//other code no need change....
<div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="button" data-index="@i" class="buttonSave" name="stringValue" value="Save" title="Save your changes" class="btn btn-outline-dark" />
</div>  

Then get the data value like below:
var index = $j(this).data('index');
console.log(index)
var formData = {
    createdBy: $j('#CreatedBy_' + index).val(),
    createdDate: $j('#CreatedDate_' + index).val(),
    updatedBy: $j('#UpdatedBy_' + index).val(),
    updatedDate: $j('#UpdatedDate_' + index).val(),
    pageTitle: $j('#PageTitle_' + index).val(),
    htmlContentCurrent: $j('#previewContent').text()
};


Thank you Rena, I will update my code accordingly to see what the view looks like in the end.
